# no main manifest attribute while running streams spring-cloud-starter-stream component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've imported the jar manually from my m2 repo:

```
app register --name file --type source --uri file://<LOCAL_PAT>/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
```

while launching the stream definition I always got in the logs this error:

> no main manifest attribute, in spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar

Can you check why there is no Spring boot or main class. Is there a specific run to be made?
(How can I use [this component](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters))

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the starter JAR file which is incorrect. The application JAR needs to be built using the appropriate binder.

You can see the instructions to build the application from the starter [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file/README.adoc#build)

Comment: when did this instructions changed? and why? it use to be that i could just do mvn clean install and could use the apps right away, do I need to also add the plugin into my pom.xml? why? Please point to some document that explains the reason to worsen the developer experience.